# Error al usar send_from_directory en Flask

Tags: python, http, flask, descarga

Hola actualmente estoy probando flask y quiero hacer que al usuario se le descargue una imagen .jpg al enviar un formulario

el directorio esta organizado de esta manera

```
├── __init__.py
├── ciudad.jpg
├── routes.py
├── t2.py
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

el archivo routes se mira de esta manera:

```
**from flask import render_template, request, send_from_directory
from app import app
import os

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index')

def form_example():
    # handle the POST request
    if request.method == 'POST':
        language = request.form.get('language')
        framework = request.form.get('framework')
        print(language)
        print(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))
        return '''
                  <h1>The language value is: {}</h1>
                  <h2>Probando {}</h2>
                  <h2> aqui {}<h2/>
                  <h1>The framework value is: {}</h1>'''.format(language, framework, 'ciudad.jpg', send_from_directory(STATIC, 'ciudad.jpg')) #send_from_directory(STATIC, 'ciudad.jpg')

    # otherwise handle the GET request
    return '''
           <form method="POST">
               <div><label>Language: <input type="text" name="language"></label></div>
               <div><label>Framework: <input type="text" name="framework"></label></div>
               <input type="submit" value="Submit">
           </form>'''**
```

ignoren las cosas incoherentes solo estaba probando si de alguna manera u otra daba. En sintesis lo que hay en la pagina es un formulario y cuando se responde devuelve una pagina con lo que respondiste y en ese momento quiero que de manera automatica se descargue la imagen. (tiene que ser asi ya que en realidad voy a poner un archivo de audio para que se descargue)

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: Segun yo se deberia descargar la imagen con ese metodo pero no pasa nada

Comment: Flask envía el archivo, luego debes ser tu quien haga la descarga. Que te aparece como resultado?